# how to output groupby to html table in flask python

Tags: python, html, pandas, flask

I have the following code to groupby data in a pandas dataframe and it works fine

```
user_data=user_data.groupby('user searched coin', as_index=False)['predicted coin'].apply(lambda x: ", ".join(f"{k} {v}" for k, v in x.value_counts().items()))
```

however when I try to render it to html in flask with

```
user_data=[user_data.to_html(classes='data')]
```

I get an error that series has not html attribute, I gather that the output from the groupby is not a dataframe.

Then I have also tried to transform into a dataframe, now I don't get the error but the output has only one column

```
user_data = pd.DataFrame(user_data)
```

is there any solution for this?

Comment: `user_data.groupby('user searched coin', as_index=False)['predicted coin']` is one column only and you are modifying it and making a dataframe from it, so it will have a dataframe with one column.

Comment: is **user_data** a data frame or a series?  I suspect you want `user_data.to_frame().T.to_html()`

Comment: user data is a csv file loaded like that
`user_data_load = pd.read_csv('static/user_searched_coins_df.csv')`
it works fine in google colab but when I run it pythonanywhere I have these issues